# Dividing count(*) sql statements to get ratios

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with one column as a web site name and one column as an action that can be done for that website. So, one row will look like this -

```
site   action
-----  ------
Yahoo  View
```

I am trying to find the ratio of one action to another. I know how I can do this for the entire table with the statement below, but I was wondering if there was a statement I could write that would return the ratios on a site-level. So I would get something like Yahoo 15%, Google 20%, etc, all listed out so I wouldn't have to have a different statement for each site. Thanks

```
select (select count(*) from practice 
where action='Like') / (select count(*) 
from practice where action='View') from dual;
```

Comment: `from dual`?  Is this Oracle?

Comment: What database are you using?  And for the record, MySQL supports `dual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you need is `group by`. Not knowing your field table names a little hard but something like this

```
Select 
     sum(case when Action = 'like' then 1 else 0 end) as CountLike,
     sum(case when Action = 'view' then 1 else 0 end) as CountView, 
     (sum(case when Action = 'like' then 1 else 0 end)/count(action)) as RatioLikeTotal ,
     (sum(case when Action = 'view' then 1 else 0 end)/count(action)) as RatioViewTotal ,
     Site 
from 
    tblLinks 
group by 
  Site
```

With the breakdown by site you can calculate the ratios in your app or against a total of all hits.

Comment: You should calculate the ratio, not just the counts.

Comment: updated for the ratios; assuming ratio is count / total rather the maths can be played with if the ratio needs to be a different number

Comment: `select count(0)` returns a 1. You should use `sum`.

Comment: And SQL Server does integer division, so the values returned would be typically `0`.  (Hint:  `1.0` rather than `1`.)  The OP still hasn't specified the database.